# OpenCV's camera in Windows 8

Tags: opencv, windows-8, camera

I use OpenCV in my project of Augment Reality. The original platform is Windows 7 and everything works perfect - full-screen with 1080p. However, when I launched my program on Windows 8 it showed live video with resolution 640x480. The same program on the same hardware, but with different OS Windows shows different results. I wrote simple test program which showed the same problem:

```
include "highgui.h"

int main()
{

cvNamedWindow("VideoTest", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

CvCapture *capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);

CvSize size = cvSize(1920, 1080);

cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , size.width);

cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT , size.height);

IplImage* frame;

while(1)

{

    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    if(!frame) break;

    cvShowImage("VideoTest", frame);

    char c = cvWaitKey(33);

    if(c == 27) break;
}

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

cvDestroyWindow("VideoTest");

return 0;

}
```

I think that there is problem with - cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , size.width); But I have no idea how to resolve it.

I would be glad any help.

P.S.

I have some new info:
I wrote test program for using of DirectShow.
It captures web camera "USB Web-camera Microsoft LifeCam Studio" into full screen live video with 1080p quality. However, when I launched this program on Windows 8 it showed only live video with 640x480 resolution.

Simple test showed that method SetFormat() of  IAMStreamConfig produces HRESULT value S_OK on Windows 7 and E_FAIL on Windows 8.

It is shown in the next listing:

```
 hr = streamConfTest->SetFormat(&mtGroup); 

 if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
 {
  printf("Success SetFormat( &mtGroup )"); 

 }else
 {
 printf("Error SetFormat( &mtGroup )");
 }
```

The first branch is chosen on Windows 7, and the second is chosen on Windows 8.

I have no idea how to resolve it. I would be glad any help.

Comment: doesn't it just mean, that the win7 driver for your cam supports resizing, and the win8 driver does not ? i think, your amstream experiment shows, that it's not opencv's fault here, but the driver for win8 is to blame

Comment: I do not think that it is the problem. I use "USB Web-camera Microsoft LifeCam Studio" and use the same drivers on both OS (this driver is included into the memory of web-cam).

Answer (score 0):

After some times I found the suitable decision of this problem. I have included Media Foundation in my project and have written simple C++ class for this. Short article about it is showed on [Capturing of video from web-camera on Windows 7 and 8 by Media Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/559437.aspx)

Comment: I have the exact same problem except I am using EmguCV (.NET C# wrapper for OpenCV).

Comment: I am not quite sure how to integrate your work into my .NET C# project. Could you provide some direction?

Comment: Can you create a defect and a pull request so as to integrate your code into OpenCV?